# how to use complex types in axis2

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, pojo

I want use complex type like MyClass[] in axis2 web service return code. Actually I choose probably easiest way for exposing my POJO class as web services described here

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-buildingservices.html#deploypojo

But axis2 is not smart enough to expose MyClass[] type to WSDL right. What I should to do? Write an mapper XML<->java class?
Actually I don't want switch to JAX-WS or use ant tasks generate.service. Is there any other way to improve deploying POJOs with complex types?

Answer (score 1):

Two days I've tryed to find a solution and when I put question here I found it after an hour... What was wrong is missing set/get public methods in MyClass. I had only public members (Integer, String) and it was not enougt (for ADB - Axis Data Binding).
I hope it helps someone else.